# (Solved) Example: $u$ not a weak limit point but $Ku$ a strong limit point, where $K$ a compact operator on Hilbert space.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, weak-convergence, compact-operators

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and $K: H \to H$ a compact opeartor. If $(u_n)$ is a bounded sequence in $H$, then $(Ku_n)$ has a convergent subsequence by definition of compact operator.

Meanwhile, by Banach-Alaoglu we see that $(u_n)$ has a subsequence which converges weakly, say to $u \in H$. Then obviouly $(Ku_n)$ has a subsequence converges strongly to $(Ku)$.

**My question is:**  Is it possible to find a $u \in H$ that, no subsequences of $(u_n)$ converge weakly to $u$, but there exists a subsequence of $(Ku_n)$ converges strongly to $Ku$?

I came across this question when I read some proofs related to compact operators which rely on the existence of weakly convergent subsequences of $(u_n)$ to find strongly convergent subsequences of $(Ku_n)$. I don't know whether this approach is essential.

**Edit:** As geetha290krm sayed in the comment, you can consider the case where $K$ is zero operator. This question is solved.

Comment: Did you consuder the case when $K$ is  the zero operator?

Comment: @geetha290krm Not until you mentioned it. Thank you!